# IIS monitoring tool

Tags: performance, iis, monitoring

I have a need for a tool that would monitor and more importantly log requests on IIS. This tool would have to report basic info about requests such as date/time of request, time spent for request, kbytes transferred... etc

What do you people use for such monitoring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should extend and add all of the IIS properties you want to log.

To do this, do the following:

1. Go into IIS
2. Select properties on
       your website.
3. Under the website tab,
       choose properties in the logging
       section.
4. Select the Extended
       Properties tab.
5. Select extended
       properties
6. Select all of the
       items you want to log.

Reset IIS.

You can now use a log parser to look through the log. http://www.smartertools.com/ has a decent one called smarter stats, and is free for a small site.

Comment: FYI: This also answered my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344693/looking-for-real-time-web-server-analytics-package

Answer (score 4):

You can use IIS's log files and read them using [Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) (free download from MS).

In response to comment: the format of the IIS log file can be found here: [IIS Log File Format (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/be22e074-72f8-46da-bb7e-e27877c85bca.mspx?mfr=true) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/676400bc-8969-4aa7-851a-9319490a9bbb.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Hm...

This is example of a record from my IIS log file:

-------------------------
07:30:16 127.0.0.1 GET /SgMART/login.aspx 401
-------------------------------------

I don't have enough information in here. What I see is only the time of the request and the response code with the page requested. 

Time consumed by the request is not shown, and also the number of bytes transfered is missing.

Maybe I'm missing something. Is it possible to add whatever fields I want to the IIS log file?

Answer (score 0):

IIS Log files + log analysers.

Log analysers like [webtrends](http://www.webtrends.com/) will give you a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

You have a look on Operations Manager from System Center family. - http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/operationsmanager/en/us/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please see the eginnovations IIS web server monitoring tool - http://www.eginnovations.com/web/iismonitor.htm